# Passing SQLite data from one view to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

I'm having trouble in passing the database of SQLite from one view to another viewcontroller which contains my tableview. I want to display all the Name and email database to the tableview.

Please take note of the codes inside //inserting, because that codes where I am having trouble with.

```
@IBOutlet var nameText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailText: UITextField!

var database: Connection!

let usersTable = Table("users")
let id = Expression<Int>("id")
let name = Expression<String>("name")
let email = Expression<String>("email")

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    //creating tableDatabase

    let createTable = self.usersTable.create {(table) in        
        table.column(self.id, primaryKey: true)
        table.column(self.name)
        table.column(self.email, unique: true)
     }
    do {
        try self.database.run(createTable)
        print("created table")
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }

    //-------------------
    //inserting

    let insertUser = self.usersTable.insert(self.name <- nameText.text!, self.email <- emailText.text!)

    do {
        try self.database.run(insertUser)
        print("Inserted user")
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }

    //listing
    let myviewcell = segue.destination as! TableViewController

    print("list tapped")
    do{
        let users = try self.database.prepare(self.usersTable)
        var namedb = String(describing: self.name)
        var eml = String(describing: self.email)

        myviewcell.name.append(namedb)
        myviewcell.email.append(eml)

        /*
        for user in users {
            print("userId: \(user[self.id]), name \(user[self.name]), email: \(user[self.email])")
        }
 */
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: please mention the problem you are facing.

Comment: You have to store data in table and get data from table in another view controller.